# ASIHTTPRequest and NSTask

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest, nstask

I was trying out ASIHTTPRequest to make downloading files easier, but now I'm getting an error about the use of an undeclared identifier 'NSTask'.

I thought NSTask was only for Mac and not for iOS? Doesn't the framework check this?

Comment: Just a small comment, ASIHTTPRequest is no longer being supported by the developer. If you just started using it I would really stress you to not use it. Switch to something like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/).

Comment: @rckoenes Good point, I've seen that it wasn't being supported anymore, but couldn't find any other decent library

Comment: As @rckoenes pointed, AFNetworking is recommended. It is an amazing framework, they work with blocks - so much easier and pragmatic than delegation. Get it!!!

Comment: @NatanR. I was just about to give it a try

Comment: For the record, AFNetworking works great so far, a joy to work with